# Variable type conversion for a view | varchar (max) to (250)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, ssms

Is it possible to convert `varchar(max)` in a table to `varchar(250)` in a view?

```
Id type int
Textxxx type varchar(max)
```

dbo.Table:

```
Id | textxxx
—--+------
 1 | aaaa
 2 | bbbb
```

Query

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.view
    SELECT ALL [Textxxx] 
    FROM DBO.Table
go
```

And I want to convert this text (`varchar(max)`) to `varchar(250)`

Totally I don't know how to do it, should I use:

```
CONVERT([Text], varchar(250))
```

???

Comment: `text` already appears to be  a `varchar`, so why do you need to convert it? Or is `text` the datatype `text`? If so you should be altering your table's definition; `text` has been deprecated for 15 years and its use should be avoided.

Comment: Text is a name of column

Comment: Then why convert a `varchar` to a `varchar`?

Comment: From varchar(max) to varchar (250), i need to apllication, which exist

Comment: Why not just use `LEFT`? *"i need to apllication, which exist"* what does that mean..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CAST or CONVERT function.

Below you can find the example

```
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW dbo.ViewsText
AS
    SELECT 
                ID
                ,TextWithCast = CAST(textxxx AS varchar(250)
                ,TextWithConvert = CONVERT (varchar(250), textxxx)
FROM 
         dbo.Table
```

Conversion from large-value data types, such as varchar(max), to a smaller counterpart data type, such as varchar, is an implicit conversion, but truncation occurs if the size of the large value exceeds the specified length of the smaller data type.